# Chromeapp set div display style

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome-app, chrome-app-developer-tool

I am  trying to create a menu-app, and ran into some trouble when trying to set the div style to "display:none;". I ran the code in jsfiddle, and it works fine. Here is my manifest:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "MenuProject",
  "short_name": "Menu",
  "description": "",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "minimum_chrome_version": "38",

  "icons": {
    "16": "assets/icon_16.png",
    "128": "assets/icon_128.png"
  },

  "app": {
    "background": {
      "scripts": ["background.js"]
    }
  }
}
```

Here is my background.js:

```
chrome.app.runtime.onLaunched.addListener(function(launchData) {
  chrome.app.window.create(
    'index.html',
    {
      frame:"none",
      id: 'mainWindow',
      bounds: {width: 300, height: 200}
    }
  );
});
```

Here is my index.html:

```
<body>  <style>
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body {
  height:200px;
 background-color: #f3f0ef;
}

.menu-container {
  -webkit-app-region: drag;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  background-color: #f3f0ef;
  padding: 0;
  box-shadow:  inset 0 0 1px rgba(255,255,255,1);
  box-shadow:  5px 5px 15px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}

.nav{
  background-color: #ed6b3a;
  height:40px;
 /* border-radius:5px 5px 0 0;*/
}

.settings {
  height:20px;
  float:right;
  background-image:url(http://i.imgur.com/CLs7u.png);
  width:20px;
  margin:10px;
}

.menu ul {
  list-style:none;
}

.menu ul li {
  border-top:1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
  padding:11px 10px;
  box-shadow:inset 0 1px 1px #fff;
  text-indent:10px;
  }

.menu ul li a {
  font-size:14px;
  color:#a4a3a3;
  font-family: 'Strait', sans-serif;
  font-size:14px;
  text-decoration:none;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #fff;
}

.menu ul li img {
  float:left;
  margin:-2px 0 0 0;
}
/*
.menu ul li:hover {
  border-left:3px solid #ed6b3a;
  background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.02);
}*/
</style>

  <script>
//var menumain = document.getElementById('menu');
function openPaste(){
//var menumain = document.getElementById('menu');
document.getElementById('menu').style = "opacity:0;"
//  menumain.style="display:none;";
}
</script>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Strait' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<div class="menu-container">

  <div class="nav">
      <div class="settings"></div>
  </div>

  <div id="menu" class="menu" style="display:block;">
      <ul>
    <li onclick="openPaste();"><a><img src="http://i.imgur.com/4JPrK.png"><p>Quick Pastebin</p></a></li></button>
    <li><a><img src="http://i.imgur.com/jHwHy.png"><p>Upload</p></a></li>
    <li><a><img src="http://i.imgur.com/Gyusy.png"><p>Location</p></a></li>
    <li><a><img src="http://i.imgur.com/mbWpc.png"><p>Contacts</p></a></li>
  </ul>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
```

When I run it in jsfiddle, clicking the "Open Pastebin" Button works fine. But when I run it as a chrome app, clicking it does nothing. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Chrome Apps do NOT allow inline scripts. You have to put your script into a different file and refer to that script file in your `index.html`.

Because of the Content Security Policy, this code won't execute. Including any inline code in your `index.html` will not work, including this:

```
<li onclick="openPaste();">
```

[Read this for better understanding](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/contentSecurityPolicy).

Comment: Check out console if there is any error message in it. There will be. (You can open the console by right click -> inspect inside your chrome app window if you run it in a dev mode). My bet is you did not changed the following part:

`<li onclick="openPaste();">`

This is an inline javascript, it won't run in chrome app. Instead you should give an id to it like "myLi". And in your script.js file create a click event listener to this object like:

`document.getElementById("myLi").addEventListener("click", function(){
    openPaste();
});`

Comment: wait...it's not working. I have this code, which listens for a button click and changes the value of a form, but it's not working....

`document.getElementById("trigger").addEventListener("click", function(){ 
  document.getElementById('urlname').value = 'hi'; });`

Comment: I can't... My administrator disabled Inspect -_- could I send you the file somehow?

Comment: just create a new question with the new source code. Anyway if you want to code without a console you will have a hard time